# How to add multiple conditions for a single column?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.x

I have many sentences that I need filter for a same column:

```
'conditions' => array('Zona.nombre LIKE' => $buscar,
                      'Zona.nombre LIKE' => 'CUPONATIC%',
                      'Zona.nombre LIKE' => 'GROUPON%'
),
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your question is not very clear but I suppose the problem is that you use multiple time the same array key

You don't even mention the cakephp version but it seems cake2

If I remember well the workaround for cake2 is putting every condition in a different array

```
'conditions' => array(
     array('Zona.nombre LIKE' => $buscar),
     array('Zona.nombre LIKE' => 'CUPONATIC%'),
     array('Zona.nombre LIKE' => 'GROUPON%')
),
```

edit: of course this way you'll have the 3 conditions joined in `AND`.

It seems more logical to put them in `OR` so

```
'conditions' => array(
    'OR' => array(
         array('Zona.nombre LIKE' => $buscar),
         array('Zona.nombre LIKE' => 'CUPONATIC%'),
         array('Zona.nombre LIKE' => 'GROUPON%')
    )
),
```

Comment: 'conditions' => array('OR' => array(
     array('Zona.nombre LIKE' => 'CUPONATIC%'),